# Google Calendar Script to sync all calendars of a domain with external database

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

We have google apps for our domain (education).  In our student database system we have all the class information.

We would like to write a sync process that forces all faculty and student calendars to be synced with google calendar.  This all seems simple enough...minus all the "what ifs" but that will just take time to figure out.

I'm currently hitting a wall when trying to decide how to authenticate with google.  Since there are limits on the amount of talking a single user can do per day I can't really have one admin user account in charge of syncing everyone.

Can someone tell me which authentication direction I should take with this?  I don't need users to log in, I just need to write to all of their calendars.   I have heard mentions of 2 legged OAuth, but I am confused on exactly what is the right answer and really need some guidance on what to use.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets of code that I used for a similar project. I used the google api and .net framework which made it a lot easier than using OAuth. These snippets are in Visual Basic

```
Imports Google.GData
Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Calendar

.....Various Property Fields for the class go here.....

Public Sub AddEvent()
    Try
        Dim theEvent As New EventEntry
        Dim theCalendarService As CalendarService = New CalendarService(FProgID)
        Dim theTime As New Extensions.When(FEventStartTime, FEventEndTime)
        Dim theEntry As AtomEntry


        If FAllDay = True Then
            theTime.AllDay = True
        Else
            theTime.AllDay = False
        End If

        theEvent.Title.Text = FEventTitle
        theEvent.Times.Add(theTime)

        If Not FDescription = "" Then
            theEvent.Content.Content = FDescription
        End If
        If Not FEventLocation = "" Then
            Dim theLocation As New Extensions.Where
            theLocation.ValueString = FEventLocation
            theEvent.Locations.Add(theLocation)
        End If
        If Not FAuthor = "" Then
            Dim theAuthor As New AtomPerson
            theAuthor.Name = FAuthor
            theEvent.Authors.Add(theAuthor)
        End If

        theCalendarService.setUserCredentials(FstrEmail, FstrPassword)
        theEntry = theCalendarService.Insert(FURLNoCookie, theEvent)
        FStatus = "Event added successfully to Google Calendar"
    Catch ex As Exception
        FStatus = "Failed: Event was added to Job List, but not Google Calendar"
    End Try
End Sub
```

In summary I was just using the Calendar Service class provided by google for the .net framework. The FstrEmail is just the email address associated with the calendar and FstrPassword is the regular google password. FURLNoCookie is actually where you specify what calendar it goes to. This is just the XML private sharing URL for the calendar (gotten from calendar settings>private address). When you first get this URL from the calendar it will look something like this

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/somebody%40gmail.com/private-188ba1932aa23d4a64ag712db232bfe8b/basic
```

Modify it to look like this

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/somebody%40gmail.com/private/full
```

A similar process can be used for updating and deleting entries. I use this to sync a spreadsheet with multiple google calendars and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that too but I think I'll end up running into potential blockages due to too many requests in a day.  We're looking at an easy 10-15k different events to be synced per day.  Did you run into troubles with this?

Comment: I did not run into any problems with this. However mine was never load tested under that high of load. The most I am doing is a hundred or so per day.